# Can we put class and its implementation in a single header file?

Tags: c++, class, header

I know template definition and its implementation can and has to put together, but how about (non-template) class?

Personally speaking I prefer put class and its implementation together if possible, since it's simplier to use, you only need to include the header file in your project, don't need to bother with the implementation files.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done, but you would force all users of your class to recompile every time you change the implementation, and recompiling will also be slower. For that you need the function definitions to be `inline`.

```
// in header
struct T {
   void f() { std::cout << "f()\n"; }
   void g();
};

inline void T::g() {
   std::cout << "g()\n";
}
```

Now the problem comes if your class has static member variables, as those need to be defined in exactly one translation units. For that you will still need to provide a .cpp.

In any case I would advise against following this approach. *When in Rome do as the romans do*, and that in C and C++ means separate compilation and division of headers and implementation files.

Comment: +1 : Saves me writing the same answer. There's also the issue of having to include all the headers that your class requires in its definition, which are probably many more than are required just for its declaration. And you can't use PIMPL.

Comment: It also means that every separate source file that includes the header file gets its own implementation of that class in its object file. It's a compilation nightmare really.

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter, yes, but the linker will sort that mess out. In that respect it's little worse than templates.

Comment: The static member issue can (sometimes) be solved by initializing them in the class definition in C++11.

Comment: @chris: I don't think so. You can (both in C++03 and C++11) provide a value for static const members of integral types (in C++11 probably any `constexpr` type), but not for mutable variables. Those need to be *defined* somewhere.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, Shoot, I must have been thinking of in-class non-static member initialization. I guess it still fits under sometimes solving the problem :p

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, yes.

The longer answer, is *also* yes, but there are valid reasons to not want to do that.  As the size (and complexity) of a project grows, a simple change to an implementation detail of a class that is used in a lot of places (say, changing of a log message or something seemingly benign), now means that all files in the project that include that file directory (*or* indirectly) need to be recompiled.  This can significantly increase your build times.

Comment: I understand that, but I am writing a small numerical library which will not execeeds maybe 20,000 lines of codes, so the building time will be acceptable for me (roughly 2-3 mins totally).

Comment: If you're building library you'll certainly have to provide headers for library users (even if it's you). And in that case you cannot provide the header with implementation included.

Comment: @user2188453 If you think 20K lines of code is small, you probably don't need our help!  But more to the point, what about the build time of code that uses your library?

Comment: @Roddy, well I am writing a dynamic-linking library, so to the users, they only get the library header and its binary implentations.

Comment: So you'll have to write the header for some classes.

Comment: Well, to the end user, its just a C library, just a collection of functions that only take primitive type numerical inputs, I just write the library with templates and some other C++ stuff.

Comment: If you are writing anything using templates as header-only, it's not a `C` library.  If you expect your users to interact with your library as a `DLL`, then it doesn't make sense to do header-only (what would actually be in the `DLL`?)